# Copying/Accessing files in Build Directory of Autotools

Tags: makefile, symlink, autotools, file-access

I have an autotools based C++ project with the following directory structure:

```
|-- Makefile.am
|-- build
|   |-- x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
|       |-- Makefile
|       |-- bin
|       |   `-- utCode
|       |-- include
|       |-- lib
|       |   |-- libCode.a
|       |   `-- libCode.la
|       |-- libCode
|       |   |-- Makefile
|       |   |-- libCode.la
|       `-- utCode
|           |-- Makefile
|           |-- utCode
|-- include
|   `-- code
|       |-- File.h
|-- libCode
|   |-- File.cpp
    |-- Makefile.am
`-- utCode
    |-- FileTest.h
    |-- FileTest.csv
    |-- Makefile.am
    |-- UtSetup.sh
    `-- code_ut.cpp
```

I have an unit test project called utCode that requires UtSetup.sh and FileTest.csv during the runtime.

When I run ./utCode from build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/utCode. The tests are failing since UtSetup.sh and FileTest.csv are missing in build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/utCode.

**Question:**

Is there a way to add a symlink or copy dependency files into build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/utCode using autotools (either in configure.ac or Makefile.am) ?